# PATCH method with enum value doesn't work with Postman but works with browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman, http-method

Here is my Spring Controller with the *@PatchMapping* :

```java
@PatchMapping("/mode/{numClient}")
public Response<Object> mode(
       @PathVariable Integer numClient,
       @RequestBody ModeEnum mode,
       @RequestHeader(name = "Authorization") String bearer
    ) throws BusinessException, NoSuchElementException {
    // Code here
}
```

With my *ModeEnum* that looks like this :

```java
public enum ModeEnum {
    @JsonProperty("A")
    AUTOMATIQUE('A'),
    @JsonProperty("M")
    MANUEL('M');

    private final Character mode;

    private ModeEnum(Character mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public Character getMode() {
        return this.mode;
    }
}
```

I use Angular as my frontend framework and this line of code

```js
this.http.patch(`${url}/${numClient}`, {mode})
```

send this within the body :

```
{
    "mode": "M"
}
```

and it works !

Now, when I try to send the same thing with Postman (or the code Postman generate), it doesn't work, I have a 400 bad request :

**Request** :
[image: Postman request]

**Headers** :
[image: Postman headers]

**Response** :
[image: Postman response]

What I tried :

- use an encapsulated object instead of using directly my Enum in both Angular and Java/Spring
- send an OPTIONS request first before trying my PATCH in Postman
- only send "A" or "M" within the body of the Postman request

But none of them worked so I'm running out of ideas :(

Comment: What are the actual values of `${url}` and `${numClient}`?

Comment: @MCEmperor Hm...It's http : / / localhost:8092/api/mode and 123, why ? The Angular http call actually works (I separated the http because it doesn't appear otherwise)

Comment: Could you show the headers set by Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sending the `Authorization` `RequestHeader` from postman.  Given that you've defined this in your handler, you either need to add `required = false`, or pass the `Authorization` header, otherwise you'll get a 400.

Comment: Ok that was just that, I'm feeling dumb...Thanks !